# .NET fill StreamReader from Textbox

Tags: c#, string, stream

I want to parse user input in a streamReader.  My code is:

```
string  txt = txtin.text ; //<~~ txtin is something like root:x:1:1....

using (TextReader reader = new TextReader( txt))
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string userName = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':'));
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.IO.TextReader'

Answer (score 11):

Use [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx). [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) is an abstract class. You can't create instances of it.

```
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(txt))
{
  //...
}
```